# How to apply one github branch rule to multiple branches?

Tags: github

I mean I want to create one rule and specify multiple branches like `dev|master`. But after seeing the doc, I think it is impossible?? Do I have to create two rules just in order to use the same rule to protect two branches?

Comment: It's disappointing that GitHub makes this so hard. https://docs.github.com/articles/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/

Comment: I've opened a community feedback post asking for [regex  as a new feature](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/53523)

Comment: i have `dev`, `qa`, `staging`, and `prod` branches I want rules for. I found it simpler to just create duplicate rules for each branch instead of having a single rule with a puzzle you have to figure out every time you look at it

Answer (score 148, accepted):

I found a rather ugly way to do this that at least gets in the ballpark (although it would be a lot better if @GitHub would give us something better than `fnmatch` with all options off...).

You can use character sets to specify the beginning characters in the repo name, like this:

```
(Using "main" branch): [dm][ea][vi]*
(Using "master" branch): [dm][ea][vs]*
```

It will match `dev` and `main`/`master` which is what you want, but the second one will also match "mastodon-rules" and "devo-is-my-favorite-band" due to the wildcard. I don't think `fnmatch` give you a "zero-or-one" quantifier like the regex `?` so it's pretty restrictive.

Github fnmatch *does* allow the negation of a character set, so if a rule is catching branches you don't want to include, you might be able to get around that:

```
(using "main" branch): [dm][ea][vi][!o]*
(using "master" branch): [dm][ea][vs][!o]*
```

This will miss the `dev` branch (it will catch `develop` and `main`/`master` though...), but it excludes "devo" so at least 'whip it' won't start playing during your next all-night thrash session with your metalhead buddies.

Admittedly, this is not a very satisfying solution. But with fnmatch this might be the best option available.

---

### **What You Should Not Do**

There are multiple other answers claiming that this pattern (or a similar variant) will work just fine:

```
[main,qa,stage,master]*
```

*DO NOT BE LURED BY THIS SIRENS SONG*

The engine treats characters enclosed in square `[]` brackets as just that: individual *characters*. Adding commas (or semicolons, or any other "separator") does not change that behavior.

**Square Brackets**: "match any one of the enclosed characters"
**Star**: "match any string of any length"

So, while this pattern will certainly match the words in the brackets, it will also match **any string of any length that starts with one of the characters in the brackets**: `[aegimnqrst,]`.

Comment: Better than creating three different rules for the same thing!

Comment: Well, better than nothing.

Comment: This format was unfortunately a bit too aggressive and caught branches I didn't necessarily want protected.

Comment: @kian I didn't include it originally, but github does allow negation of a character set. I added the syntax to my answer. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the followup @Z4-tier! My core envs I want to protect follow a `dev` / `qa` / `preprod` / `master` naming convention; so I think for the case of having many variable branch name lengths, 4 separate rules deliver better results here; at least I only need to do this "once" !

Comment: I just wonder why Github doesn't use regex for this thing.

Comment: @SeonghyeonCho If I had to guess, it might be because branch rules are evaluated on the github server, so from a security perspective it's really a way for untrusted users to inject parameters into the code that runs whenever the branch rule is evaluated. Since regex can be extremely inefficient (it's not hard to write one that would take years to run), a bad actor that controlled enough accounts could use this to orchestrate a DDOS attack.

Comment: `[dm][ea][vi][!o]*` for `develop` and `main`!

Comment: Not the answer I expected and all I have to contribute is [w][t][f]*

Comment: This is unbearably complex and feels like just an excuse for some GitHub engineer to justify working hard. I can't honestly understand any other justification for doing this.

Answer (score 13):

Have also been trying to get my head around this this this morning, I believe you(/we) may have to create two identical rules for each branch oddly. At least that's what I believe after reading through:

https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Apply-a-single-branch-protection-rule-to-both-master-and-release/td-p/11587

Comment from Moderator:

> "No, there isn't a way to do that in the "Apply rule to" box. As
>   stated in the protected branches documentation, we use the fnmatch
>   library to match branch names to the match expression. There is a
>   feature that would allow for matching two rules like that if there is
>   a flag enabled but we don't enable that flag in our environment."

OR you could use this solution if you want to apply one rule to all branches beginning with or including the same matching phrase:

https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Branch-Protection-on-multiple-branches/td-p/10519

Comment from Community Manager:

> Branch protection rule patterns are based on fnmatch syntax. You could
>   use releases/v?.? to automatically protect branches like
>   releases/v1.0, releases/v2.0, and releases/v2.1. And
>   [1-9]-[0-9]-stable could automatically protect branches like
>   1-0-stable, 2-0-stable, and 2-1-stable.

Answer (score 8):

Following z4-tear great explination
This will cover `development` `master` and `staging`

```
[dms][tea][avs]*[iet][ne][gtr]
```

Comment: This is a great option as it won't allow something like `master-blahblah`

Comment: Still allows `saving`, `master-killing`, `mesmerizing`, `mea-culpa-later`, `seater` and `session-testing`. But for sure, the set of matching branches is smaller.

Answer (score 7):

to apply to all, add --> `**/**`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that need a rule for covering only dev and main, its possible with this syntax:

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/File.html#method-c-fnmatch

`[cd]*[vd]`

**CONS**

Will match with everithing that starts with c or d, and ends with v and d

Answer (score -3):

Based on the explanations above, `[mds][aet][iva][neg]*` works for `develop`, `staging`, and `main`. Of course, it also matches other combinations.

Answer (score -6):

Enable it on develop, master but not test

```
[develop;master]*[!test]*
```

Comment: This will enable it on any branch where the first character in the name is any of the characters `[adelmoprstv;]` and the rest of the string does not contain any of the characters `[est]`.

Answer (score -14):

According to the [GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/administering-a-repository/configuring-protected-branches), they use the [fnmatch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/File.html#method-c-fnmatch) library for the pattern field. That syntax allows an alternation:

> **`{a,b}`**
>
> Matches pattern `a` and pattern `b` if `File::FNM_EXTGLOB` flag is enabled. Behaves like a Regexp union (`(?:a|b)`).

For your problem, the pattern you’re looking for might be `{dev,master}`.

I don’t know what they mean by “if `File::FNM_EXTGLOB` flag is enabled”, so this might not work.

Comment: This answer should be deleted.

Comment: This is the only correct answer when it comes to `fnmatch` _except_ GitHub doesn't seem to pass the required `File::FNM_EXTGLOB` for this to actually work.  But, syntax-wise, this is the only correct answer and what one would expect to work given GitHub's use of `fnmatch`.

Answer (score -19):

They already enable wildcards. So this pattern works:

```
[main,qa,stage,master]*
```

Comment: @James This doesn't do what you think... This will match **any word, of any length, that starts with any of the characters in the square brackets**, which is over 200,000 dictionary words (it will match "steves_branch" and "testing" and a lot of other things that you probably don't want) The accepted answer shows how to avoid that.

Comment: my bad I see that now. I'm using [Mm][Aa][sSiI][tTnN]* to match either main or master