# Create one branch protection rule for multiple branches in Github

Tags: git, github

I have multiple branches like **develop, master, sit, uat, testbed, preprod, etc..** in my Github repository.

I want to create **one branch protection rule** for **multiple branches**.(above mentioned branches)

I am aware that same branch protection rule can be created multiple times for each branch.But this is time consuming and not an efficient way.(Since all the branches need the same rule)

Please provide any suggestions or solutions.

Comment: Afaik, Git doesn’t control branch protections.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply github branch rules to two branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53135414/how-to-apply-github-branch-rules-to-two-branches)

Answer (score -4):

Use `[main;develop]*` when you want to add rule for branches main and develop. Just write all the branches you want to add in the square brackets `[]` and separate them with semicolon `;`. At the end add `*`

Comment: this answer is incorrect / it does not do what you think it does. it matches any string that starts with one of the characters in the brackets, followed by any number of characters